# Что такое Entity и View Object в ADF

Tags: java, framework, oracle-adf

Объясните, пожалуйста, на примере из реальной жизни, что такое Entity и View Object в ADF.

Answer (score 0):

Очень грубо: `Entity` это данные, а `View` визуальное представление данных.

По сути это компоненты [паттерна MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller)

Answer (score 0):

**Вот вам пример из жизни:**

**Entity** - это своего рода флешка с данными, а **View** - это представление этих данных на экране монитора.

**Entity** - это данные берутся, например, из бд.

**View** - это представление этих самых данных (html страничка)

Answer (score -1):

На примере из реальной жизни, `entity` это таблица или вьюшка БД, `view object` это грубо говоря `sql` запрос, в нем может быть обращение к нескольким `entity`.

Comment: Реальная жизнь у вас какая то мрачная, у других это знакомые, приобретаемые товары, музыка, погода наконец.

Comment: Как грица, я сделал, что смог, пусть те, кто смогут, сделают лучше.